# React Native - Margin or Padding Not Working on Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, flexbox

Below is the code for my component. Problem is that I cannot add any space in between the buttons, only on Android emulator as you can see in the image. Right now you see `marginBottom` but if I replace it with padding, it still does not work.
Appreciate if anyone has an idea why is this happening.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Button title="Sign In" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn')} style={{ marginBottom: 20}}/>
        <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    header: () =>  false
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you are using react-native-elements, and style prop is not vailable on that component, I can see on the documentation try using this prop "buttonStyle" to style the button and if not possible wrap the button around a view,

Thanks

Comment: You are the man! Yes, I totally did not pay attention to that and because it worked on ios (don't know why). I did not think of it. buttonSyle works fine! Thank you!